# Pass var to jsp to EXTjs

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, extjs

i have a big doubt, i want to pass a var that i get in another page by get method, to my servlet to pass that value to my front content page in EXTjs, but i dont know how i can do this, i paste some code where i supose i must do this.

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "El usuario que usa esto es " + usuario );
    //GestorBBDDOracle Gesto = new GestorBBDDOracle();

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tipoPapel.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

I want to pass the var "usuario" to the EXTjs, i dont know if i must use my jsp or i can pass direct to my js.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access a variable from a JSP in your ExtJS.  Here is a way to do that:

In your jsp, define a hidden field with your value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVariable" value="<%=usuario%>" />
```

Then in your ExtJS, access it like this:

```
var value = Ext.fly('myVariable').dom.value;
```